# fetch join table data using eloquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, model

I am new to laravel & want to implement eloquent relationship.

Let me explain.

Consider I have 2 tables

products

```
 product_id
 product_name
 brand_id
 price
```

brands

```
 id
 brand_name
```

Each product will have one brand Id.But in Brands table, there is no product id.  One brand_id can be in multiple product rows, and one product has one brand_id only. I want to select some col from products table plus brand_name with respect to brand_id of products table using Model.SO in Product model I wrote:

```
public function brands()
    {   
        
        return $this->hasOne('App\Brand','product_id');
    }
```

and in Brand model I write:

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','brand_id');
    }
```

Now I want the result:

```
product_name
price
brand_name
```

How can I fetch those data in controller using eloquent relation? Also, the way I wrote Model relationship, Is it ok??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **Product Model** relation will be below

```
public function brand(){   
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand','brand_id');
}
public function product(){   
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id');
}
```

Now in controller you can add query as below.

```
$products = Product::with('brand','product')->get();
echo '<pre>'
print_r($products->toArray());
exit;
```

Comment: thanks , Its working fine. I have a question, is it OK to place both brand() and product() function in Product Model?? can you please explain the reason behind it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely fine. Right now you have 2 foreign keys in the same table. In the future one table has many relationships. Example, In the user model there are many relations like user can create a product, user role, a user post,. Simply if your table related to multiple foreign key then you can define it in model.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you want a `one-to-many` relationship, so one brand can have many products and many products belong to one brand.

Product model:

```
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
}
```

Brand model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Then you would be able to get the brand information like this:

The full brand model:

```
Product::first()->brand
```

The brand name:

```
Product::first()->brand->brand_name
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

> A one-to-many relationship is used to define relationships where a
> single model owns any amount of other models. For example, a blog post
> may have an infinite number of comments.

P.S.:

Your table column names do not make much sense to me, why do you have `product_id` on products but then on brands it is just called `id`? Why do you have `product_name` but then just `price`? why is it not just `name` or `product_price`, so your at least consistent?

Comment: You are right. Actually I should give some meaningful column names